# How to resolve problem with error mapping types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper, blazor

I am trying to make a form in Blazor wasm, which allow me to add `Recipes` to database. I have 3 domain objects: `Ingredient`, `Recipe` and `IngredientRecipe`. I am using DTO concept and i have corresponding to domain objects 3 DTO's classes: `IngredientDto`, `RecipeDto` and `IngredientRecipeDto`. Form for adding `Ingredients` works fine. Problem is when i trying to create a new `Recipe`. Error message shows me errors in 2 classes: RecipeMapper and RecipeController. My error is related with mapping domain object to DTO and i dont know how to resolve this. Please give me some advice how to repair this

Full error

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
      
      Mapping types:
      RecipeDto -> Recipe
      CookBook.Shared.Data.Dto.RecipeDto -> CookBook.Shared.Entities.Recipe
      
      Type Map configuration:
      RecipeDto -> Recipe
      CookBook.Shared.Data.Dto.RecipeDto -> CookBook.Shared.Entities.Recipe
      
      Destination Member:
      ListOfIngredients
      
       ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
      
      Mapping types:
      IngredientRecipeDto -> IngredientRecipe
      CookBook.Shared.Data.Dto.IngredientRecipeDto -> CookBook.Shared.Entities.IngredientRecipe
         at lambda_method83(Closure , IngredientRecipeDto , IngredientRecipe , ResolutionContext )
         at lambda_method82(Closure , Object , Recipe , ResolutionContext )
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at lambda_method82(Closure , Object , Recipe , ResolutionContext )
         at CookBook.Server.Mappers.RecipeMapper.Map(RecipeDto recipeDto) in C:\Users\48510\source\repos\CookBook\CookBook\Server\Mappers\RecipeMapper.cs:line 32
         at CookBook.Server.Controllers.RecipesController.Post(RecipeDto recipeDto) in C:\Users\48510\source\repos\CookBook\CookBook\Server\Controllers\RecipesController.cs:line 58
         at lambda_method42(Closure , Object )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
      
      HEADERS
      =======
      Accept: */*
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
      Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
      Connection: close
      Content-Length: 164
      Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
      Host: localhost:44332
      Referer: https://localhost:44332/recipes/create
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
      origin: https://localhost:44332
      sec-fetch-site: same-origin
      sec-fetch-mode: cors
      sec-fetch-dest: empty
      
System.ApplicationException: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
RecipeDto -> Recipe
CookBook.Shared.Data.Dto.RecipeDto -> CookBook.Shared.Entities.Recipe

Type Map configuration:
RecipeDto -> Recipe
CookBook.Shared.Data.Dto.RecipeDto -> CookBook.Shared.Entities.Recipe

Destination Member:
ListOfIngredients

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
IngredientRecipeDto -> IngredientRecipe
CookBook.Shared.Data.Dto.IngredientRecipeDto -> CookBook.Shared.Entities.IngredientRecipe
   at lambda_method83(Closure , IngredientRecipeDto , IngredientRecipe , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method82(Closure , Object , Recipe , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method82(Closure , Object , Recipe , ResolutionContext )
   at CookBook.Server.Mappers.RecipeMapper.Map(RecipeDto recipeDto) in C:\Users\48510\source\repos\CookBook\CookBook\Server\Mappers\RecipeMapper.cs:line 32
   at CookBook.Server.Controllers.RecipesController.Post(RecipeDto recipeDto) in C:\Users\48510\source\repos\CookBook\CookBook\Server\Controllers\RecipesController.cs:line 58
   at lambda_method42(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: close
Content-Length: 164
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:44332
Referer: https://localhost:44332/recipes/create
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
origin: https://localhost:44332
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty

   at CookBook.Client.Repositories.RecipeRepository.CreateRecipe(RecipeDto recipeDto) in C:\Users\48510\source\repos\CookBook\CookBook\Client\Repositories\RecipeRepository.cs:line 30
   at CookBook.Client.Pages.Recipe.RecipeTest.SaveRecipe() in C:\Users\48510\source\repos\CookBook\CookBook\Client\Pages\Recipe\RecipeTest.razor:line 121
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

My domain classes

```
 public class Ingredient : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Kcal { get; set; }
        public virtual List<IngredientRecipe> IngredientRecipe { get; set; }
    }

public class Recipe : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<IngredientRecipe> ListOfIngredients { get; set; }
    }
public class IngredientRecipe : BaseEntity
    {
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    }
```

My DTO

```
public class IngredientDto : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Kcal { get; set; }
        public List<IngredientRecipe> IngredientRecipe { get; set; }
    }

 public class RecipeDto : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<IngredientRecipeDto> ListOfIngredients { get; set; } = new List<IngredientRecipeDto>();
    }

 public class IngredientRecipeDto : BaseEntity
    {
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public IngredientDto Ingredient { get; set; }
        public RecipeDto Recipe { get; set; }
    }
```

RecipeMapper, there is an error

```
 public class RecipeMapper
    {
        private IMapper mapper;

        public RecipeMapper()
        {
            mapper = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<Recipe, RecipeDto>()
                      .ForMember(dest => dest.ListOfIngredients, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.ListOfIngredients))
                      .ReverseMap();
            }).CreateMapper();

        }
        public RecipeDto Map(Recipe recipe)
        {
            return mapper.Map<RecipeDto>(recipe);
        }

        public Recipe Map(RecipeDto recipeDto)
        {
            //at this line is error
            return mapper.Map<Recipe>(recipeDto);
        }

        public List<RecipeDto> Map(List<Recipe> recipes)
        {
            return mapper.Map<List<Recipe>, List<RecipeDto>>(recipes);
        }
    }
```

And RecipeController, error in Post method

```
 public class RecipesController
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext context;
        private readonly RecipeMapper mapper;

        public RecipesController(AppDbContext context, RecipeMapper mapper)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<RecipeDto>>> Get()
        {
            var ListOfRecipes = await context.Recipes
                .Include(x => x.ListOfIngredients)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Ingredient)
                .ToListAsync();

            var ListOfRecipesDto = mapper.Map(ListOfRecipes);

            return ListOfRecipesDto;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<RecipeDto>> Get(int id)
        {
            var recipe = await context.Recipes
                .Include(x => x.ListOfIngredients)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Ingredient)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            var recipeDto = mapper.Map(recipe);

            if (recipe == null) { return new NotFoundResult(); }

            return recipeDto;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Post(RecipeDto recipeDto)
        {
            //here is error
            var recipe = mapper.Map(recipeDto);

            context.Recipes.Add(recipe);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return recipe.Id;
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
            var recipeToRemove = context.Recipes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

            context.Recipes.Remove(recipeToRemove);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Maybe problem is with my form so I'm giving a github link
https://github.com/szymonJag/CookBook/blob/master/CookBook/Client/Pages/Recipe/RecipeTest.razor

Comment: Yes sure, I just edited the post

Comment: You should use `ProjectTo` instead. http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

For me it feels like you are migrating and older project and use the old way of AutoMapper. In the docs says: "Starting with 9.0, the static API is no longer available." The exceptions also says that mapper is unable to find the mappings.
The new way to do this is to create Profiles and configure the mapping there. The profiles should be registered in used DI.

Example for a Profile:

```
public class RecipeProfile: Profile
{
    public RecipeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Recipe,RecipeDto>();
    }
}
```

For registering the profile in DI (in Startup.cs):
`services.AddAutoMapper(profileAssembly1, profileAssembly2 /*, ...*/);`

After that you can use `ProjectTo` or `IMapper _mapper`. I recomment the `ProjectTo` if you are using EF Core. This slightly modify your queries SELECT statement to only query for the mapped properties.

I used AutoMapper docs as reference.

[Configuring AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html)

[AutoMapper DI](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html)